# Is there a proper way to quote or reference long functions?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

I just edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881028/what-is-the-default-jsonconverter-used-in-json-net/18750150#18750150) to correct the link rot, and I realize that the official policy is that it's better to include a copy of the function than to merely provide a link. However, [the method](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L148) is over 60 lines long. Since it's not my answer, I'm not going to substantially change what it says, but I do think it would be appropriate to include a more durable reference to the function mentioned. Stack Overflow doesn't have folding regions, and copying the whole function would cause clutter.

Is there any proper editorial technique besides rewriting (someone else's post) so as to not mention a whole function?

Comment: (1) Actually [so] does have folding region, if you abuse JS code snippet. (2) There is a limit on number of displayed lines anyway, exceeding that would show a scroll bar on the code block. (3) 60 lines is not that long.

Comment: @user202729 Feel free to post (2),(3) as an answer.

Comment: @user202729 It's pretty long for an answer

Answer (score 7):

I know that it is lengthy code, but link rot is annoying for those that seeks help to find a problem on his/her question. If he/she ends up on that answer and wants to click the link, he/she gets a 404. That must be annoying. You can consider to search further. Yet, sometimes there are enough keywords to find back the code. Or at the other side: sometimes you cannot.

I would say: include the code with a reference to the GitHub repository (and preferably with a date when it got copied over). Just fill in the edit summary (I hope that I am not the only person that checks it) that the edit is made to prevent link rot.

Comment: When you include it, make sure that the source license is compatible with the cc by-sa 3.0 license used on SO.

Comment: That is a valid point yes. However, codes from non-public accessible sources (or published with licenses that does not allow reproduction) are not so lenient to be posted on StackOverflow IMHO. Yet you can take over the strategy of the code if there are no alternatives.

Comment: *and preferably with a date when it got copied over* — better yet, link to a specific source control **tag** or **commit**. For example, on GitHub, you can press `y` to change the current URL to a permalink using the commit hash you are looking at.

Comment: @Shepmaster Linking to a specific commit is progress, but it doesn't fully solve the problem of link rot. What if Stack Overflow outlives Git Hub?